# Swift extra trailing newline when reading file

Tags: swift, file-io, swift3

I am making an app where my levels are stored as grids of numbers in a text file, and when reading them in, I keep getting a trailing newline when there isn't one. The content of the text file being read in is the following (note there is no trailing newline, the last line just ends). Ignore the tick marks, they are there for clarity to mark the beginning and end of the file content.

```
'1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0'
```

My code:

```
let mypath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"level1", ofType:nil)!
let content = try! String(contentsOfFile:mypath)
let lines:[String] = content.components(separatedBy:"\n")
print("lines=\(lines)")
print("content = '\(content)'")
```

Output:

```
lines=["1 1 0 0", "1 0 0 0", "0 0 0 0", "0 0 0 0", ""]
content = '1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
'
```

As you can see, there is a fifth array element, implying that there were four "\n" strings found in the file, when there were only three. Plus the value of content has an extra newline at the end.

---

Now if I add a trailing newline to the file such that the file content is (everything between the tick marks):

```
'1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
'
```

The output becomes:

```
lines=["1 1 0 0", "1 0 0 0", "0 0 0 0", "0 0 0 0", ""]
content = '1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
'
```

It's the exact same as before!

---

If I add two trailing newlines, then the output accounts for it, becoming

```
lines=["1 1 0 0", "1 0 0 0", "0 0 0 0", "0 0 0 0", "", ""]
content = '1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

'
```

Why is this? Is it a bug? Is there any way I can turn this "feature" off? I need to count the number of lines, and this is throwing off everything. I know I can trim off all the extra newlines, but that just seems like a patch to avoid the problem rather than a fix to the problem itself.

Comment: Why don't you store your data in a proper format? Instead of being dependent of a damn new line character in a file, that could be added or missing by accident...

Comment: @EricAya I agree it probably should be in a different format, but this file format is a good example of why this "feature" could be a problem.

Comment: What I'm saying is: you can't rely on newline characters in a file. It is a known problem that you may have sometimes a trailing character that you didn't add on purpose. Some text editors are also rather lax with how they handle newline characters. Some even add one at the end of the file! To me, you made an experience, it's interesting, but it stops there: if you really need to store this information for your app, don't store it like that. :)

Comment: Check out this excellent answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303613/txt-files-with-invisible-line-breaks